# Codeigniter Bcrypt Implicit conversion from Error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

bcrypt I am getting an error while generating and comparing password using bcrypt

Error Message :

> Message: Implicit conversion from float 48.8 to int loses precision

Filename: libraries/Bcrypt.php

Line Number: 217

Code

```
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->_iteration_count / 10);
    $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->_iteration_count % 10);
```

Bcrypt Link : https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt/blob/master/libraries/Bcrypt.php

Error Functions: gensalt_blowfish

Thanks to everyone who knows the problem.

Comment: That library was last updated over 10 years ago, and PHP has since gotten bcrypt support in core.

Comment: i solved the problem, for those who have problems  $output .= chr(ord('0') + intval($this->_iteration_count / 10));